# Cannot access Firestore within a HTTP Trigger of Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to store my values from the request body to the cloud firestore and sent back the foruminsertdata.Name back in the response. But I am not able to do this.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin =require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 
if(req.method === 'POST'){
foruminsertdata = req.body;
db.collection('forum').add({
     Name: foruminsertdata.Name,
     Description: foruminsertdata.Description,
     Heading: foruminsertdata.Heading,
     PostedOn: foruminsertdata.PostedOn,
     Status: foruminsertdata.Status,

 })
 .then(ref => {
     console.log('Added document with ID: ', ref.id);
     return res.status(200).json(
         {
         message: foruminsertdata.Name
     });
 })
 .catch(err => {
     console.log('Error getting documents', err);
   });

 res.json({
     message: foruminsertdata.Status,

 });
 }

})
```

I don't know what is happening...Whatever I do I always get the output as

```
{
message: foruminsertdata.Status,
}
```

in which "foruminsertdata.Status" has some value that I give
but what I expect the output as

```
{
    message: foruminsertdata.Name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is immediately returning `foruminsertdata.Status` to the client without waiting for the promise from the database operations to resolve.  Any function that returns a promise is asynchronous and returns immediately.  Execution will continue in the callbacks you attach to it.

I'm not sure why you have two calls to `res.json()` in your code, but if you want to send a response only after your query completes, you'll remove the second one and just send a response after the query is done.  You will probably also want to send a response in the `catch` callback as well to indicate an error.

Comment: I changed the code as you told me now I get the following error(only some part) also I get the response message given inside '''catch''' statement

"Error getting documents Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field
 Error getting documents Error: The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field
>      at JWT.fromJSON (E:\Projects\firebase\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\jwtclient.js:165:19)
>      at GoogleAuth.fromJSON (E:\Projects\firebase\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:294:16)"